# Regex capture group that is sometimes there

Tags: regex, grouping

I've been banging my head against the wall for hours trying to figure this out. I'm trying to capture three groups *if* they're there and if not, capture everything in the first group. I can break this out into separate regex statements but keeping one would be awesome.

The 4 different strings would be like the following:

```
Be somewhere now & be there later (Store) @1300
Be at work! @1430
Go home whenever (Home)
Don't ever go to the donut shop.
```

The end result I'm looking for is like the following:

```
(Group 1) Be somewhere now & be there later (Group 2) Store (Group 3) @1300
(Group 1) Be at work! (Group 2) (Group 3) @1430
(Group 1) Go home whenever (Group 2) Home (Group 3)
(Group 1) Don't ever go to the donut shop. (Group 2) (Group 3)
```

The best I can do so far is handle the 1st and 2nd option and only grabbing Group 3. I've done this with this:

```
.*(?:\(.*\))?\s(\@\d+)$
```

I'm pretty sure the `.*` is going to have to be removed because if I turn it into `(.*)` it always matches everything.

I've tried every which way I know but can't get it to work so now I reach out to you. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(.*?)(?:\(([^)]+)\))?(?:\s+@(\d+))?$
```

The key is that `.*?` is a non-greedy match. It will match as little as possible, so it won't match the entire string unless the other groups fail to match.

See it working online: [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/9hALv1Vk4V)

Comment: Close!!! The only part needed now is removing the `(` and `)`. Once that's done, I'm sure I'll be able to strip out the `@` as well.

Comment: @LouisCarreiro: Like this? `^(.*?)(?:\((.*?)\))?(?:\s+@(\d+))?$` http://rubular.com/r/09CIQC7Ne4

Comment: Amazing!!! That's exactly it! Thanks Mark!!! If you have any extra spare minutes, could explain what you did there and what I was failing to see?

Comment: @LouisCarreiro: As I mentioned in the answer, the key point is that you should be using `.*?` (match as little as possible) instead of `.*` (match as much as possible). The rest is almost the same as what you already have.

Comment: Thanks for that! I'll commit that to memory.

Comment: Extra question... I know I didn't include it earlier but, is there a way to handle `(` and `)` earlier in the line? Somethine like:

`Be somewhere (this is a test) now & be there (Test) @1430`

I ran it through and this is what I got:
http://rubular.com/r/7dFECvgsOY

Expecting something like:
`(Group 1) Be somewhere (this is a test) now & be there (Group 2)Test (Group 3) 1430`